# Redirecting email from from domain registrar to hosting comapny mailbox

Tags: domain-name-system, email, hosting, mx-record

I have the domain example.com registered with company A

I have the hosting with company B (ServerGrove)

Company A offers me simple parking, and company B offers me mailbox service. What I would like is to use the hosting company mail service.

How do I configure the DNS records in company A to be forwarded to company B mailbox? I think I have to add a MX record to company A's configuration, and then the same in company B's DNS records, is this correct?

I think I'm mixing concepts, and cannot see a clear solution, I've tried several configurations but all failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to ask companyB for the dns servers, (like ns1.companyb.com, ns2.companyb.com). Add those dns servers to your domain. Then in companyB dns administration you need add an MX DNS record in order to point emails to your servers IP address. But that is not all, to have your emails delivered to inbox and not rated as spam you also need to add a SPF record.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I found this SPF configuration example, added as a TXT entry **v=spf1 ip4:111.222.333.444 a mx a:mail.hostname.com ~all** Do I have to add this to the company A's DNS entry list? The IP address and mail.hostname.com should be replaced with company B information?

Comment: No, mail.hostname.com should not be replaced with companyB ip, it is the domain. I would suggest you a better way to generate the SPF. Use MSN's step-by-step wizard SPF id generator: http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/

Comment: Well, your answer solved my problem, I must have tried that configuration in one of my tries but missed the mail because it was going to the spam folder as you noted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

1st ask you mailbox provider to create you hosting Account on his server and ask him about his MX record. after getting MX record ask your company A to change you Mx record with Company b Mx Record.
and after 24 hours your email box will be configured on company B hosting server.